# \n (newline) not working in doctesting

Tags: python, for-loop, printing, newline

I have a code

```
        song_num=1
        for song in self.songs:
            result+='\n'+str(song_num)+'. '+str(song)
            song_num+=1

        return str(result)
```

In doc test multiple line string not returnit in multiple lines, it gives "\n" line instead

> ```
> Expected:
>     '''CAnadian artist (8:18)
>     A, B (3:15)
>     AA, BB (5:3)
>     '''
> Got:
>     'CAnadian artist (8:18)\n1. A, B (3:15)\n2. AA, BB (5:03)'
> ```

How can I got expected result in doctest?print works perfect but doctest not

Comment: how exactly do you print result? If you are using REPL and just type `result` then it must return string with `\n`, but if you try `print(result)` then it will actually make new lines instead of showing `\n`

Comment: I am using unit testing where expected and real not match

Comment: you return line numbers but don't expect them?

Comment: When you use doctest, the output `repr` has to match exactly. The text you see in the REPL – that has to be your docstring. `\n` escapes, single quotes, and all. (And make the docstring raw.)